# Movie that involved conical shaped sand traps with creatures in the sand at the bottom

Tags: story-identification, movie

It’s a movie that I watched when I was a kid in the mid 80’s. The main character was either an alien type himself or wore a mask to protect himself from the sand. This movie had conical shaped sand pits that had creatures at the wait under the sand as soon as you fell into them.

Comment: What's the setting of this film? Present day Earth? An alien planet?

Comment: Also, are there any films with similar creatures that you can rule out for us? Like _Star Wars: Return of the Jedi_, for example.

Comment: There are sand traps that are conical with dangerous alien creatures in the bottoms in the movie ENEMY MINE. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy2wbgzUaD0

Comment: Giant antlion-like alien menaces are very common in visual science fiction media.  See here for the real-life inspiration:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2K3v29zeOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be [Enemy Mine](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089092/) from 1985.

Here's a clip on youtube which shows sand pits like you describe (though what the clip doesn't show is that the pits are completely conical and motionless until disturbed):

In this film we see the pit creatures eat turtle-like aliens:

[image: an alien "mock turtle" being captured by a sand pit creature]

There are a couple of scenes where our main characters nearly fall prey.

There are mostly just two characters in the film, one human and one alien humanoid who... well it looks like a man in a mask to be fair.